# python2.7 draw simple polygon without self-intersection

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polygon, shapely

I want to draw simple polygon that means there is no self-intersecting in the polygon using x & y locations. But what I got for the result is butterfly shape of polygon.

I know that if I change `li_feasible_points` to `[[0,2],[2,2],[4,0],[2,0]]` in order to draw simple polygon IN THIS TIME.

But WHAT I WANT is to draw simple polygon without self-intersecting by ANY list of corner points locations. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is my code and my result below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

x_lim = 5
y_lim = 10
x = np.linspace(0, x_lim)
y = np.linspace(0, y_lim)

li_feasible_points = [[0.0, 2.0], [4.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 2.0]]
line = plt.Polygon(li_feasible_points, closed=False, color='r', fill=True, edgecolor='r')
plt.gca().add_line(line)

plt.xlabel(li_var_names[0])
plt.ylabel(li_var_names[1])
plt.xlim(0, x_lim)
plt.ylim(0, y_lim)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I look forward to your help. Thank you.

Comment: Possibile duplicated with question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263284/create-non-intersecting-polygon-passing-through-all-given-points

Comment: yes, it is! thank you!!