# Is it possible to always form a simple polygon from all set of given co-ordinates in 2-D?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, coordinates, polygon

Hello community memebers !!

I was solving [CONTAIN](https://www.codechef.com/JUNE20A/problems/CONTAIN) problem from this month's Codechef Long Challenge and I couldn't solve it.

So I read the editorial and most of the things were clear to me but there was one question I couldn't get my head around.

And that is :

**Is it always possible to form a simple polygon from any set of given co-ordinates in x-y plane using all of the given points ?**

Comment: Yes. Examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263284/create-non-intersecting-polygon-passing-through-all-given-points